# Why is my Tic-tac-toe minimax implementation so slow?

Tags: c++, tic-tac-toe, minimax

My very simple minimax algorithm for Tic-tac-toe is running at about 5 million nodes per second. Even though this is enough to find a Tic-tac-toe move in 0.1s, it's way less than other programs. For example, [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U4ogK0MIzqk&t=600s) shows at 10:00 that the speed for calculating chess moves (which are a lot more complex) is about 20 million nodes per second. [This website](https://chessify.me/blog/nps-what-are-the-nodes-per-second-in-chess-engine-analysis) shows that Stockfish can run a full chess engine at 5 million nodes per second on a normal PC.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

int board[3][3];
int nodes = 0;

bool isFull()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            if (board[i][j] == 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}

bool equals3(int a, int b, int c)
{
    return a == b && b == c && a > 0;
}

int checkWin()
{
    for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++)
    {
        if (equals3(board[row][0], board[row][1], board[row][2]))
        {
            return board[row][0];
        }

        if (equals3(board[0][row], board[1][row], board[2][row]))
        {
            return board[0][row];
        }
    }

    if (equals3(board[0][0], board[1][1], board[2][2]))
    {
        return board[0][0];
    }

    if (equals3(board[0][2], board[1][1], board[2][0]))
    {
        return board[0][2];
    }

    return 0;
}

int negaMax(int turn)
{
    nodes++;

    if (isFull())
    {
        return 0;
    }

    int win = checkWin();
    if (win != 0)
    {
        return (win == turn) ? 1 : -1;
    }

    int bestScore = -1;

    for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
        {
            if (board[x][y] == 0)
            {
                board[x][y] = turn;
                int score = -negaMax(3 - turn);
                board[x][y] = 0;

                if (score > bestScore)
                {
                    bestScore = score;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return bestScore;
}

int main()
{
    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    negaMax(1);

    auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> timePassed = end - start;
    
    std::cout << "Nodes searched: " << nodes << "\n";
    std::cout << "Time passed: " << timePassed.count() << "\n";
    std::cout << "NPS: " << nodes / timePassed.count() << "\n";
}
```

I am not sure how I can improve this program even further and the lack of speed is showing in my chess move generation.

Comment: @anastaciu Nodes searched: 549946; Time passed: 0.112094; NPS: 4.90611e+06. Is it any different if you run it?

Comment: I'm getting Nodes searched: 549946
Time passed: 0.041227
NPS: 1.33395e+07

Comment: `isFull()` can be optimized by simply tracking how many moves have been played

Comment: I do not know if inlining the loop in `checkWin()` would make it faster or not. Probably depends on the compiler.

Comment: `return (win == turn) ? 1 : -1;`.  One can never win on their turn, so this can be optimized, for a tiny speed boost.

Comment: You also appear to have the standard benchmarking issue that you aren't controlling for or checking cpu speed. When you start the program, the cpu is usually running very slowly in order to save power, and it takes it a few seconds before it'll speed up. So if the total time is <10 seconds, the cpu is still probably deliberately running slowly.  Try running the code several times in a loop, and _then_ timing it.

Comment: Also, since the highest possible score is `1`, then if `score` is 1, it can immediately return without checking any more child nodes.

Comment: I also suspect that the chess engines are counting pruned nodes in their counts, despite not actually analyzing them.

Answer (score 0):

Because for the Minimax algorithm you should use Alpha Beta pruning (it don't consider unnecessary sub-trees: [Alpha-beta pruning - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha%E2%80%93beta_pruning)). However the 'minimax' function (probably called negaMax in the code) should separate when maximizing or minimizing respectively in PC's turn and player's turn.

Comment: I'm aware of alpha-beta pruning, however it just decreases the number of nodes and doesn't increase the speed per node, so I just left it out to showcase the problem

Comment: Sorry but I have not other ideas (for now).

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using an int array to represent the broad, consider using a int8_t, where each binary value represent a state, then use bit operations to manipulate or find status of the board. Your nested for loop and other operations inside the recursive function will hurt when millions of nodes are traversed.

Use of alpha beta prunning and hash tree to record previous search values can improve search speed significantly.

Comment: Each cell can have three states, which means you either (A) need a type that can hold 3^9= 19,683 different values (int16) and a ton of code to compress/uncompress values, or (B) 4^9 = 262,144 different values (int) where each cell uses 2 bits.  So I can't tell if your answer is suggesting an array of int8, or packing the whole array into an int32.

Comment: Either way, since his entire algorithm probably fits in cache, I suspect an array of int is indeed fastest.

Comment: On the other hand, cramming the entire board in an `int` would allow potential caching strategies, which might help...